# Python formatting decimal points on specific columns which contain 'nan'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am loading a dataframe from a csv file using,

```
df_c = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dir_w, csv_c))
```

Which gives me,

```
   SubCase        Row1   Row2    Row3   Row4
0  1003001          NaN     0     NaN   10.0
1  1003002          NaN     0     NaN   10.5
2  1003003          NaN     0     NaN   11.3
3  2000001     110001.0    10     1.0   9.81
4  2000002     110001.0    10     1.0   5.06
```

For columns 'Row1' and 'Row2' I want to remove the decimal points, while keeping the decimal points in 'Row4'. So it looks like this,

```
   SubCase        Row1   Row2    Row3   Row4
0  1003001          NaN     0     NaN   10.0
1  1003002          NaN     0     NaN   10.5
2  1003003          NaN     0     NaN   11.3
3  2000001       110001    10       1   9.81
4  2000002       110001    10       1   5.06
```

I have tried the following code with no luck,

```
na_mask = df_c['Row1'].notnull()
df_c.loc[na_mask, 'Row1'] = df_c.loc[na_mask, 'Row1'].round(decimals=0)
```

and

```
na_mask = df_c['Row1'].notnull()
df_c.loc[na_mask, 'Row1'] = df_c.loc[na_mask, 'Row1'].astype(int)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't control the decimal representation in the working DataFrame, if you want to export, then specify the export format or eventually convert to strings. Another option might be to use the Int64 dtype: `df['Row1'] = df['Row1'].convert_dtypes()`

Comment: Thanks mozway, works a treat. Also thank you for answering my other questions.